# How to achieve quadcopter autonomy after successful implementation of 2D SLAM using RPLidar and "hector_slam" ROS package in indoor environments?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, path, avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a **Naza M Flight Controller** which can give me the IMU readings (I don't know if I can extract this information by interfacing it with ROS, else I will have to use an external IMU). I also need suggestion for a sonar sensor (my application is for indoor environments) to integrate elevation data in *hector_slam* . Further, is it even possible to achieve autonomy with an RPLidar, IMU data and Sonar Data?

looking forward!
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254260/hello!-i-am-working-on-autonomous-flight-of-quadcopter-for-indoor-environments.-currently-i-have-an-rplidar-and-successfully-implemented-2d-slam-using-%22hector_slam%22-ros-package.-what-should-i-do-next-to-achieve-autonomy?/) by [rosfun](https://answers.ros.org/users/29313/rosfun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can achieve autonomy with RPLidar.
Check out my post on the next steps and it will help you. [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/256924/rviz-lidar-tf-hector-slam-plz-help-error-messagelookuptransform-base_link-to-laser-timed-out-could-not-transform-laser-scan-into-base_frame/)

---

Originally posted by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) with karma: 96 on 2017-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosfun](https://answers.ros.org/users/29313/rosfun/) on 2017-03-28**:
Thanks for the help. Will check it out.